# How to prune lantana plant back to life

Tags: pruning

I have a slow dieing lantana plant which even with re-potting dropped all leaves and I basically put it under sun with no water to die...few days back as I was doing regular checkup on my balcony garden to my surprise I saw new baby leaf coming out of one of branches of about to die lantana plant.

I notice leaves growing on one part (single branch) the other branch seems dead weight , would it be okay I can break or prune down to length of other branch which is growing leaves? thanks.